# Entity Framework: New parent is saved, new children are not

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class ParentObject {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public List<ChildObject> ChildObjects { get; set; }
}

public class ChildObject {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method for adding a new parent with a new child:

```
private void Add(string parentName, string childName) {
    using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext ()) {
        ParentObject newParent = new ParentObject { Name = parentName };
        ChildObject newChild = new ChildObject { Name = childName };
        newParent.ChildObjects = new List< ChildObject> { newChild };    
        context.ParentObjects.Add(newParent);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The parent is saved to the database, but the child is not. It is my understanding that having the foreign key constraint should tie everything together (the foreign key exists on the DB tables). I can't figure out what I'm missing to make the child save to the database.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (I tried in a console application)

Comment: it looks strange in how you set the `[ForeignKey("ParentId")]`, if using just `DataAnnotation`, it requires that you need to declare a navigation property `Parent` in the `ChildObject` class and apply `[ForeignKey("ParentId")]` on that property. Otherwise I think you need to use fluent api. The problem could be your tables/model are not setup/configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The collection property needs to be `virtual`

```
public virtual ICollection<ChildObject> ChildObjects { get; set; }
```

It's like this with any navigational property, not just collections. Without the `virtual` keyword, EntityFramework's dynamic proxies are unable to override the property and do the foreign key tracking you want it to do.

Comment: It does not need to be virtual. I tried in a console application, without virtual... and it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

In your ChildObject create a property of the instance Parent.

```
public ParentObject Parent { get; set; }
```

Entity framework will detect there is a foreign key. You can also add a ForeignKeyAttribute.

Comment: You don't need to have a bi-directional navigation property to get this to work.